# Debug MapReduce code which is using distributed cache concept

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

We are trying to debug a simple mapreduce code where we have added the files using

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("hdfs://lmaster.hdp.com:8020/input/StopWords.txt"), job.getConfiguration());

DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("hdfs://lmaster.hdp.com:8020/input/paintings"), job.getConfiguration());
```

the path of hdfs

When I run it using eclipse I am getting the following error

```
2013-12-05 14:34:24,522 INFO  [Thread-12] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(397)) - Map task executor complete.
2013-12-05 14:34:24,566 WARN  [Thread-12] mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:run(482)) - job_local206806739_0001
***java.lang.Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/tmp/hadoop-cdh-hadoop/mapred/local/1386234263343/StopWords.txt (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:403)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/tmp/hadoop-cdh-hadoop/mapred/local***/1386234263343/StopWords.txt (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.context.ContextMapper.populateList(ContextMapper.java:117)
```

I am unable to proceed further or debug the code.Please help.

Comment: please post the code segment where you retrieve the files from the cache.

Comment: @Davis Broda, We retrieve the distributed cache file in the following way BufferedReader stopWords = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(localFiles[0].toString()));
  while((stopRecord = stopWords.readLine()) != null )
  {
   stopList.add(stopRecord.toLowerCase().trim());
  }
  Collections.sort(stopList);
  stopWords.close();